# Как менять содержимое страницы в зависимости от введения изменений в БД?

Tags: javascript

Хочу понять, как работает изменение содержимого страницы у одного пользователя, когда другой пользователь делает что-либо.

К примеру, мессенджер: человек пишет сообщение другому, другой сидит в чате, ничего не нажимает и не делает и получает это сообщение и оно выводится в мессенджере, хотя он ничего не перезагружал. Как это происходит? Тут же только в БД обращаться, когда с JS sql запросы не пишутся.

Comment: Ну в данном случае вам стоит рассмотреть Web сокеты

Comment: JS тем или иным образом отправляет запросы на сервер, а сервер уже делает что хочет со своей БД

Comment: И что, то есть мне надо каждую секунду писать запрос к серверу, проверяя, есть ли изменения в БД, чтобы отображать измененное содержимое?

Comment: Во-первых — да, это вполне вариант который 10-15 лет назад активно использовался (а где-то используется до сих пор). Во-вторых, сейчас уже есть упомянутые в первом комментарии вебсокеты, через которые сервер сам может прислать уведомление в js-скрипт

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Однако лучше бы вы ответили именно полноценным ответом, чтоб я решение отметил.